# In what situation is a file placed in the resources of a JAR, but is not accessible in a class' ClassLoader?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm just trying to read in a simple .txt file into my java project using this.class.getResourceAsStream(filename). I have several files within main/resources, and almost all of them return an object when I try to get them as an input stream. The only object I can't read in is my text file.

I have placed the file with all of the other resource files that are readable by the classloader, but it appears this file wasn't placed in the class' classLoader for whatever reason. If I unzip the jar, the file is still included with the jar in the same directory as all of the other resources, so it seems to be being built correctly.

I guess what I'm asking is at what point do I tell Java what files I want to be included as a resource in a class' ClassLoader? Is it something that should be done when the jar is built if things are in the correct place (i.e main/resources)?

Here is what the code looks like, and it's respective return values, when running for the file it can find and the file it can't, that are both located in the same place.

```
// This is not found. Both are placed at src/main/resources
def tmpDict = this.class.getResourceAsStream("dict.txt")

println tmpDict // null

// This is found
def tmpDict2 = this.class.getResourceAsStream("calc.config")

println tmpDict2 // sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@2dae5a79
```

Comment: you should maybe post a screenshot of your project, or a small project reproducing this issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info i'd say the path is wrong. when i used just "file.txt" for the path it got NPE

i [used this method](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/io/how-to-read-data-from-inputstream-into-string-in-java/) to read from the stream. The file was located at `\src\main\resources\static\file.txt`
This worked in eclipse, packaged into jar and worked there too.

```
public String getFile() throws Exception {
    InputStream in = Controller.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("static/file.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.defaultCharset()));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
    }        
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is, essentially, what I am doing as well. I'll edit the original post to show the exact code.

Comment: Strange, that it finds the config and not the txt. i'd try ClassLoader as it seems it will search from root instead of current package. or try "resources/dict.txt" for the path to give it a hint

Comment: you may have a copy of calc.config at a path it can reach .maybe a copy. i'm not able to repro your issue. it will read both if using  this.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() from resources dir.

Answer (score 0):

Some very Basic checks:

The file must be case-sensitive (as it is not a Windows file), and special characters of the file name might be cumbersome. Also check that the file in your project has the file extension not twice (.txt.txt - Windows hiding the extension).

Check that `getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c/A.txt")` indeed gives a null.

If not the reading might go wrong on the encoding.

Comment: I have a feeling you're right and it is something I'm just overlooking, but it is not any of those problems, unfortunately. The extension is correct, the capitalization is correct (all lower case) and the getResourceAsStream call is in fact returning a null.

Comment: Then: use `X.class.getResource...` with X an existing class in the jar. The path is class (package subdir) relative, so use a leading slash. `/dict.txt`